# Hiding scope variable tooltip in Chrome's script debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

When I step through code in Chrome's JavaScript debugger, I regularly run into a situation where a variable tooltip gets stuck and stays on screen, obscuring code that's behind it. Clicking off the tooltip or on other scope variables doesn't help, and the only way to fix this is usually to close and reopen the Inspector pane, which ends the debugging session.

Is there any better way to hide the tooltip when it decides to stick around?

[image: Chrome variable tooltip]

Comment: I ended up logging a bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68642

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this same problem in safari 5.1.1 on mac OS 10.6, very annoying, I have to close the web inspector - not just minimize - and reopen to get rid of it and it happens often.