# how do i remove this yellow box while debugging javascript using web inspector in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, web-inspector

[image]

How do I remove that yellow box? It stays in the same spot regardless of where I move the cursor. If I am not using an external monitor, that yellow box took up half of my screen :(

Thanks!

PS: I am asking here because there does not seem to be a good forum to ask the official webkit/safari crowd or I just miss it but it is not webkit.org

Comment: I think you should move to SuperUser.

Comment: can you elaborate on what that is please?

Comment: @infoSetu this is in regards to a development tool, so it is on topic here.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556041/hiding-scope-variable-tooltip-in-chromes-script-debugger

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* that it stays in the same spot no matter where you move the cursor? What should happen, and what does happen for me, is that it appears when you mouseover a particular variable,
[image: Screenshot showing Script debugger in Safari with tooltip displayed]
but disappears when the mouse is moved off the variable (and off of the "tooltip") after about a second.

Stick your mouse in the upper right corner of the screen for a second and it should be gone. I'm assuming that, as large as your tooltip was, you moved the mouse over the tooltip itself (and we just can't see it since the OS X screen capture does not include the cursor).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long-lasting bug in the Web Inspector code. Some work has been done towards fixing it. Please give a try to a more recent version of the browser, and if you still can come up with a reliably reproducible case, please add a comment to http://crbug.com/95189 with the case description.